# What is the docker command to run jenkins container in windows

Tags: jenkins, docker, linux-containers, docker-for-windows

What is the correct `docker run ...` command to run jenkins container.

1. What are the required ports?
2. How to mount volume D:\jenkins folder to jenkins job configuration path?

I'm using linux containers on windows 10.

Comment: Have you tried the examples in the [official docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/)?

Comment: docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /your/home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins. How to mount D:\jenkins folder instead  /your/home. Linux notation doesn't work in windows

Comment: That seems like something someone would have tried before, or [asked about it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33126271/how-to-use-volume-option-with-docker-toolbox-on-windows/39181789#39181789)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v //D/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home jenkins
```

or with `:` `-v D:/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home` like in example below but i personally prefer first approach.

just make sure in docker settings you have checked disc `D` to allow mounting `D`

[image: Share Drives settings example]

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE for new docker-for-windows versions:

Make sure under Docker `Settings > Resources > FILE SHARING`,
The host path exists in this list, else you should add it.

In your example, you should check `D:\jenkins`

Comment: i don't have shared drives or file sharing in my recent docker desktop