# download file with Rselenium & docker toolbox

Tags: r, docker, download, rselenium

I m trying to download files by Rselenium but it looks impossible.I don't arrive to download even with an easy example:

#### 1) i have installed docker toolbox (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-docker.html)

#### 2) i ran the firefox standalone image : 3.1.0 and now i m testing the older 2.52.0

#### 3) i have installed the rselenium package on My R X64 3.3.2 and i read all the questions & answers on stackoverflow

#### 4) i have tried the following code, by the way, when i analyse the firefox options about:config , i don't find the "browser.download.dir" options:

```
require(RSelenium)
fprof <- makeFirefoxProfile(list(browser.download.dir = "C:/temp"
                             ,  browser.download.folderList = 2L
                             , browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting     = FALSE
                             , browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk =  "application/zip"))
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "firefox",remoteServerAddr = "192.168.99.100",port = 4445L,extraCapabilities = fprof)
remDr$open(silent = TRUE)
remDr$navigate("https://www.chicagofed.org/applications/bhc/bhc-home")
# click year 2012
webElem <- remDr$findElement("name", "SelectedYear")
webElems <- webElem$findChildElements("css selector", "option")
webElems[[which(sapply(webElems, function(x){x$getElementText()}) == "2012" )]]$clickElement()

# click required quarter

webElem <- remDr$findElement("name", "SelectedQuarter")
Sys.sleep(1)
webElems <- webElem$findChildElements("css selector", "option")
webElems[[which(sapply(webElems, function(x){x$getElementText()}) == "4th Quarter" )]]$clickElement()

# click button

webElem <- remDr$findElement("id", "downloadDataFile")
webElem$clickElement()
```

#### 6) i have no error but i have no file

#### 7) At the end , i would like to download the excel file on this page by Rselenium:

[link]https://app2.msci.com/products/indexes/performance/country_chart.html?asOf=Feb%2028,%202010&size=30&scope=C&style=C&currency=15&priceLevel=0&indexId=83#

Comment: Th download directory would be on the docker container which is a linux container. This location would then be mapped to an appropriate directory on the host machine (windows in your case)

Comment: many thanks, it seems logical

Comment: So you would use a docker command such as `docker run -d -v //c/test/://home/seluser/Downloads -p 4445:4444 -p 5901:5900 selenium/standalone-firefox-debug:2.53.1` and then refer to `browser.download.dir = "/home/seluser/Downloads"`

Comment: In fact , i have just read this page which explains the trick:[link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#mount-a-shared-storage-volume-as-a-data-volume). and i have just run the following command: `code`docker run -d -p 4445:4444 --name web -v //c/temp:/downloads selenium/standalone-firefox:3.1.0     no error but always no files

Comment: You are mapping C://test on the HOST to /downloads on the container. There is no folder /downloads on the container. The appropriate folder to map to on the container is `/home/seluser/Downloads`

Comment: ok but how do you know the directories and the files of the container?

Comment: answer: docker exec -t -i containername /bin/bash        [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813486/exploring-docker-containers-file-system)

Comment: You can attach to a running container using the above. The user `seluser` is also listed in the various project dockerfiles for example https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/master/Base/Dockerfile

Comment: my command: 'docker run -d -p 4445:4444 --name web -v //c/temp:/downloads selenium/standalone-firefox:3.1.0' is ok. When i explore the container. the directory downloads is well created. but when i run my command with rselenium, still "no error" but the directory downloads stays empty.

Comment: `/downloads` is in the root directory will `seluser` which is the user running the firefox browser in the container have access to it?

Comment: i think he has access but to be sure i have just tested with the following container directory: //home/seluser/Downloads. no error but still empty.. when i explore //home/seluser/Downloads with ls -Al, i get drwxr_xr_x 2 root root for Downloads

Comment: You will also need to set the download directory in firefox. `browser.download.dir = "/downloads"` or `browser.download.dir = "home/seluser/Downloads"` depending on wherein the container you want downloads directed to. Also note the discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42476693/rselenium-hangs-in-navigate-to-direct-pdf-download/42488105#42488105 in relation to newer versions of firefox and issues with setting preferences for geckodriver. I would recommend using image tagged 2.53.1 which is firefox 47

Comment: i set browser.download.dir="/home/seluser/Downloads" and i use the 2.52.0 version and still empty: i m going crazy

Comment: Yes I have installed Docker toolbox on a windows 10 machine and outlined the steps as an anwser. I assume the question I linked to earlier was using the newer Docker for windows.

Comment: I have already tried the new docker for windows with my core i5 and my windows 10 pro but it didn't work despite i have all teh requirements . maybe need probably to get more gb of ram or 2 xeon

Comment: @Kevin did you manage to solve your issue then? Hardware specs are not the problem

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Docker toolbox with windows you may have issues mapping volumes see [Docker : Sharing a volume on Windows with Docker toolbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34161352/docker-sharing-a-volume-on-windows-with-docker-toolbox)

> If you are using Docker Machine on Mac or Windows, your Docker daemon has only limited access to your OS X or Windows filesystem. Docker Machine tries to auto-share your /Users (OS X) or C:\Users (Windows) directory.

I initiated a clean install of docker toolbox on a windows 10 box and ran the following image:

```
$ docker stop $(docker ps -aq)
$ docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
$ docker run -d -v //c/Users/john/test/://home/seluser/Downloads -p 4445:4444 -p 5901:5900 selenium/standalone-firefox-debug:2.53.1
```

NOTE: **we mapped to a directory in the Users/john space. User john is running docker toolbox**

Running the below code

```
require(RSelenium)
fprof <- makeFirefoxProfile(list(browser.download.dir = "home/seluser/Downloads"
                             ,  browser.download.folderList = 2L
                             , browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting     = FALSE
                             , browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk =  "application/zip"))
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "firefox",remoteServerAddr = "192.168.99.100",port = 4445L,extraCapabilities = fprof)
remDr$open(silent = TRUE)
remDr$navigate("https://www.chicagofed.org/applications/bhc/bhc-home")
# click year 2012
webElem <- remDr$findElement("name", "SelectedYear")
webElems <- webElem$findChildElements("css selector", "option")
webElems[[which(sapply(webElems, function(x){x$getElementText()}) == "2012" )]]$clickElement()

# click required quarter

webElem <- remDr$findElement("name", "SelectedQuarter")
Sys.sleep(1)
webElems <- webElem$findChildElements("css selector", "option")
webElems[[which(sapply(webElems, function(x){x$getElementText()}) == "4th Quarter" )]]$clickElement()

# click button

webElem <- remDr$findElement("id", "downloadDataFile")
webElem$clickElement()
```

And checking the mapped download folder

```
> list.files("C://Users/john/test")
[1] "bhcf1212.zip"
>
```

Comment: well done: i will try tomorrow. But for my case even the mapping has a limited access, the downloaded file would have been available on the directory of the container. something is probably wrong with my installation

Answer (score 1):

finally i have decided to make a clean install of the docker for windows (17.03.0) stable.
i needed to decrease the number of available cpu (to 1) and available ram too (to 1GB).
i have shared my c too (btw it s mandatory to have a password session otherwise you can't share the directory
after that i restarted my computer
On the R side , do not forget to remove the: 
    remoteServerAddr = "192.168.99.100"
and i got the file.

#### my fear now is about the stability of docker, sometimes it runs, sometimes not.

### many thanks john for your help