# How to Dockerize multiple python scripts within a .sh script?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have shell script which contains multiple python scripts (which are run one after another and not in parallel).I need to know how can I dockerize this?

This is My shell script(this takes in one argument of path) -

```
#!/bin/bash
#parameter from shell
parameter_directory="$1"
# Python script 1
python script1.py --outpath $parameter_directory

# Python script 2
python script2.py $parameter_directory 

# Python script 3
python script3.py $parameter_directory

#Python script 4
python script4.py $parameter_directory

#Python script 5
python script5.py $parameter_directory

#Python script 6
python script6.py $parameter_directory
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add an example shell script that's similar to yours? Please use formatting options and don't post code as a screenshot.

Comment: @Oresztesz Hi, Have edited the question.Hope it'll help to answer the question.These python scripts are Machine Learning scripts which are run one after the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a folder which has all your files plus your shell script. Let's say the shell script is named as `entrypoint.sh`. The directory will look like the following:

```
Dockerfile
entrypoint.sh
script1.py
script2.py
script3.py
script4.py
script5.py
script6.py
```

Notice, that there's a `Dockerfile` which will contain the following information:

```
FROM python:2-slim
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

Build your docker image using the following command:

```
docker build -t python-sandbox .
```

Finally, run your created image in a container using the following command:

```
docker run -ti --rm --volume parameter_directory:/parameter_directory python-sandbox /parameter_directory
```

Be aware that Windows and Mac have some limitations when it comes to mounting volumes.

[Docker: Sharing a volume on Windows with Docker Toolbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34161352/docker-sharing-a-volume-on-windows-with-docker-toolbox)

Comment: @Nikhil - consider accepting the answer if it works for you.